# ASP.NET core 2.1 localized identity url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I am creating a new ASP.NET core 2.1 project and I have created a route to include the language code at the beginning (Website.com/en/Home/Index).

```
app.UseRouter(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=" + DefaultCultures + "}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
             {
                 subApp.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

                 mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                     name: "default",
                     template: "{culture=" + DefaultCultures + "}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                 });
             });
        });
```

I have scaffolded the Identity code into my project and it created the Identity Area making the Login Url Website.com/Identity/Account/Login.

I would like to know if it's possible to make the route the same with the language code?
Preferably Website.com/en/Account/Login but if that's not possible Website.com/en/Identity/Account/Login would work.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, and even configuring:
`services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(opt =>
{opt.LoginPath = new PathString("{culture=en}/Home/Login");});`
doesn't help :/ doesn't override anything.